# Separating substrings from space separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex, csv

I have data in a single column that I need to sub-string out into a new table. My issue is that sometimes the length of the data in the first column is either 10 or 9 characters, then in the second column it's 9 or 8 characters, so I can't find a uniform way to sub-string out each separated piece of data.

The data looks like this:

```
1465723732 353812955 2 88903391 N L 2016-06-28 13:48:57 2017-06-30 00:12:43 5
990459128 264834338 1 67093407 Y L 2001-01-01 00:00:00 2016-07-09 08:10:20 20
269660184 91753484 1 23492107 Y L 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2013-04-23 09:10:12 15
```

When the second column is 8 characters, the first is 9 characters. The pieces of data are only seperated by one space rather than evenly into columns , so substringing takes digits from the next piece of data and so on.

Could anyone suggest a method of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but may I say that this data should never even be in a MySQL database?  You should have scrubbed this data into separate columns before bringing it into MySQL, and there are many tools/languages which are great for such text manipulations.

Comment: Now that you are stuck with the data in MySQL, you are fairly limited as to what you can do.  The base string functions won't help much, not without massivey ugly code.  You could try looking into using a UDF, but that also seems unattractive to me.  Best bet is to scrub the data outside and bring it back in.

Comment: If your data is all the same as your sample, and if you are on a recent version of SQL Server, then you could try using the new STRING_SPLIT command using a delimiter of a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not elegant but it will help you shape the data:

```
WITH testdata(col) AS (
    SELECT '1465723732 353812955 2 88903391 N L 2016-06-28 13:48:57 2017-06-30 00:12:43 5' UNION
    SELECT '990459128 264834338 1 67093407 Y L 2001-01-01 00:00:00 2016-07-09 08:10:20 20' UNION
    SELECT '269660184 91753484 1 23492107 Y L 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2013-04-23 09:10:12 15'
), tempdata(cols) AS (
    SELECT CAST('<col>' + REPLACE(col, ' ', '</col><col>') + '</col>' AS XML)
    FROM testdata
)
SELECT
    cols.value('/col[1]', 'INT') AS col1,
    cols.value('/col[2]', 'INT') AS col2,
    cols.value('/col[3]', 'INT') AS col3,
    cols.value('/col[4]', 'INT') AS col4,
    cols.value('/col[5]', 'CHAR(1)') AS col5,
    cols.value('/col[6]', 'CHAR(1)') AS col6,
    cols.value('/col[7]', 'DATE') AS col7,
    cols.value('/col[8]', 'TIME(0)') AS col8,
    cols.value('/col[9]', 'DATE') AS col9,
    cols.value('/col[10]', 'TIME(0)') AS col10,
    cols.value('/col[11]', 'INT') AS col11
FROM tempdata
```

Output:

```
col1       | col2      | col3 | col4     | col5 | col6 | col7       | col8     | col9       | col10    | col11
-----------+-----------+------+----------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------
1465723732 | 353812955 | 2    | 88903391 | N    | L    | 2016-06-28 | 13:48:57 | 2017-06-30 | 00:12:43 | 5    
990459128  | 264834338 | 1    | 67093407 | Y    | L    | 2001-01-01 | 00:00:00 | 2016-07-09 | 08:10:20 | 20   
269660184  | 91753484  | 1    | 23492107 | Y    | L    | 2000-01-01 | 00:00:00 | 2013-04-23 | 09:10:12 | 15
```

Comment: Wait... so there is exactly one space? It is easier then. Please edit your OP and paste exact data without formatting.

Comment: @Tommy you changed the database! Anyway, see revised answer.

Comment: You may want to consider using `CROSS APPLY` so that the replace and conversion to XML appear only once rather than duplicated.